# Optimize UpdateOrCreate in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I download XML from external URL and parse it into mysql.

```
Rate::updateOrCreate([
    'exchanger_id'      => $exchangerId,
    'signature_from_id' => $signatureFromId,
    'signature_to_id'   => $signatureToId
], [
    'in'     => $item->in,
    'out'    => $item->out,
    'amount' => $item->amount
]);
```

The thing is XML contains many items, and I parse many sites, so it results into 20K queries for 20-25 URLS. Later on I'll parse about 300 URLS and the number of queries will rise.

How could I optimize this process? I mean the `updateOrCreate` part. If a row with `exchanger_id`, `signature_from_id` and `signature_to_id` exists I need to update it, otherwise create a new row. And repeat it for every xml item.

As I realize Laravel makes at least 2 queries: first is a `select` which checks out if the row exists, second is `create/update`.

Couldn't think about any batch examples :(

**Update**

I made a unique composite key for first three columns (exchanger_id, signature_from_id, signature_to_id) and downloaded this trait https://github.com/yadakhov/insert-on-duplicate-key

Number of queries become 26 (was about 20000). But the amount of time required to handle all this didn't change. What am I missing...

Answer (score 0):

Why not do this instead if your business case allows it.

(1) Store all the xml in bulk in some folder in your app

(2) Create Cron job that will do the processing for you and fire an event that you can capture when the processing is complete so you can take the next step? Take a look at scheduling jobs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scheduling). Also take a look at queues and eventing in laravel [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#job-events) for some more advance ideas.

Comment: Well, what's the difference between inserting XML on the fly, or by reading XML files stored in some folder. Anyway I need to insert or update a lot of rows, doesn't matter where I get them: from file or from somewhere else...

Comment: Well, the difference is synchronous vs asynchronous operation. You can do both storing files(reading) and then inserting records in DB asynchronously if your use case allows it.